# Conflicting implementation for a newtype

Tags: rust, traits

I have a wrapper type that is currently a String, but can be changed later on.
I want to provide users of the type an `Into` trait that they can keep their own code while the wrapper type implementations may be changed at will.

Something like this:

```rs
struct Wrapper(pub String);

impl std::fmt::Display for Wrapper {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

impl<D> From<D> for Wrapper
where
    D: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn from(display: D) -> Wrapper {
        Wrapper(display.to_string())
    }
}
```

However, this will not compile, because `From<std::fmt::Display>` will also try to implement `From<Wrapper> for Wrapper`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Possibly with specialization (which is currently an unstable feature). But I'd argue this is very unintuitive design from a Rust perspective. It would be more reasonable to offer a `from_display` method on the object's inherent `impl` and use that instead. You can't call it with `.into()`, but `from_display` is completely unambiguous then.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The input to the wrapper type could be a `&str`, `u16`, etc. I want to minimize client code changes when the underlying library changes

Comment: I think that's fine. If you write `pub fn from_display<D>(display: D) -> Wrapper` in your `impl Wrapper`, then you can call it as `Wrapper::from_display(...)` for any `Display` type. Rust will infer the generic argument type.